# Location of ~./mavenrc

Tags: bash, maven, path

I was setting up maven on OS X machine when I encountered the error :

```
JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE.
```

On changing the JAVA_HOME variable to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home` and updating the **PATH**  variable it still didn't work.

Turns out, JAVA_HOME reads from `~.mavenrc` and not bash_profile.

So we have to update the JAVA_HOME in `~.mavenrc`. But how do I know the location of the same?

Comment: Good chance it's `~/.mavenrc`, that is, a file called `.mavenrc` in your home directory.

Comment: If you correctly export JAVA_HOME it will work from `bash_profile` but I recommend to use `.mavenrc` cause it's more flexible...

Comment: You can run `mvn -v` to verify the JAVA_HOME used by maven. Also, if you haven't created a `~/.mavenrc` file, you most likely don't have one. The problem could be that you haven't exported JAVA_HOME correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` indicates the `$HOME` directory, so it should be there. The dot behind the file name indicates it's a hidden file, you have to activate `View > Show Hidden Files` to see it.